# How to install the standard environment in a computer not only in a shell

Tags: nix

If I install the stenv , I install a list of command  like gnu make, sed...

[source](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-tools-of-stdenv)

I only need to do execute

```
nix-shell -p
```

in oder to load the stdenv in a shell.
I don't need to give a package name. But I don't find in the documentation (the link I've given) where this information is.

Now I would like to install the stdenv on my computer, not only in a shell.

I've tried to execute

```
 nix-env -iA
```

But it doesn't work.

```
  nix-env -iA stdenv
```

doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This command install stdenv

```
 nix-env -iA nixos
```

If you don't use nixos. I should try this:

nix-env -iA nixpkgs

But I still don't know why

```
  nix-env -ia  nixos
```

is equivalent to

```
 nix-env -iA nixos.stdenv
```

And I still dont't know why I don't find stdenv in the packet manager.
As you can see :

https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.11&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=stdenv